# Query on matching json array keys

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a json field in mysql called `column_info`. Here's an example value:

```
[{"id": ["132605", "132750", "132772", "132773", "133065", "133150", "133185", "133188", "133271", "133298"]}, 
 {"number": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]}, 
 {"id": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]}
]
```

Is it possible to do a query that does the following:

```
keys = ['id', 'number', 'id']
SELECT * FROM `column_info` WHERE JSON(??) = keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
SELECT `column_info`
FROM
  `table`,
  (SELECT @`keys` := '["id", "number", "id"]') `init`
WHERE (
  SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_UNQUOTE(
        JSON_EXTRACT(
          JSON_KEYS(`der`.`keys`),
          '$[0]'
        )
      )  
    )
  FROM
    JSON_TABLE(
      `column_info`,
      '$[*]'
      COLUMNS(
        `keys` JSON PATH '$'
      )  
    ) `der`
) = CAST(@`keys` AS JSON);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7J9pjcdMPFkMbzB9JoUnG/1).

Comment: wow, that's pretty complex for doing a json query. Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately, I'm using mysql5.7, which doesn't support some of the above, but I tested it in the db-fiddle and it's pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL are your running?

If it's v8, you can try JSON_CONTAINS()

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html